# Why "чьи это книги" and not "чьи эти книги"?

Tags: грамматика, узус

When one should chooser "чьи это книги?" and when "чьи эти книги?". Or are these forms completely interchangeable?

Comment: There's a whole set of related questions on this site. Have a look at this one with my detailed answer: [What is the difference in meaning between “Это моя машина” and “Эта моя машина”?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9349/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-Это-моя-машина-and-Эта-моя-машина/9352#9352).

Comment: and another one http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13068/parts-of-speech-in-the-question-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE/

Comment: Exactly why you are saying "**It** **was** **they** who made it possible" (maybe not literally, but your example and mine are close)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will it make sense to you if I say, "because **это** is a picture-frame rather than a tag"? In other words, **это** refers to the abstract, uncountable "stuff we're looking at", rather than to be a marker attached to the books themselves, as in the English "Whose books are these?". You *can* ask **Чьи эти книги?**, but it will sound weirdly "off", at least if you were pointing to the actual books. The variant with **эти** can (at least in some cases) sound natural when what you're asking is "whose are these books?" rather than "whose books are these?" – i.e. when "these" is a contextual reference rather than a literal indication. But even there, I must say, I can't quite come up with satisfactory everyday examples. The abstract, independent, generalising **это** is just so much more common.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases people say "it's just as it is". Note:we use a declined  form of this determiner«Эта книга чья? Эти книги чьи?» only before the noun in emphatic sentences.Used in post- position the pronoun is not declined and the sentence sounds more neutral. Though we can't deny grammaticality of a declined pronoun used in postposition, we don't use it as a rule.